# What is the correct way to enable source downloads in CentOS 8-stream?

Tags: centos, repository, sendmail, source, source-code

So I tried to do this:-

```
yumdownloader --source sendmail
```

But hit this problem:-

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:48 ago on Wed 16 Dec 2020 10:34:00 AM GMT.
No package sendmail-8.15.2-34.el8.src available.
Exiting due to strict setting.
Error: No package sendmail-8.15.2-34.el8.src available.
```

So I made sure epel etc is installed, and I enabled all things in /etc/yum.repos.d - but there's no existing source info.

The CensOS doc unhelpfully says this:-

```
Source RPMs will also be published once the release is done, in the usual location at http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/

From a CentOS machine you can easily retrieve sources using the yumdownloader --source <packagename> command.
```

Their definition of `easily` is clearly different to *mine*.

Now; the *stream* release is not /8/ in "CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo" - it is actually /8-stream/ - and sure enough, I can find my sendmail binary in `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/sendmail-8.15.2-34.el8.x86_64.rpm` - as you can tell from `` cd /etc/dnf/vars;cat `grep . *` ``  which reveals their variables thus: `contentdir:centos infra:stock stream:8-stream` (the CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo base URL is `http://mirror.centos.org/$contentdir/$stream/AppStream/$basearch/os/` )

HOWEVER...

`https://vault.centos.org/centos/8-stream/` contains only empty folders - no repodata or source files, and the /8/ tree does not contain the stream source ... grrr.

I created the below to enable all the /8/ Source files, but `sendmail-8.15.2-34.el8.src.rpm` is not one of them :-(

`cat CentOS-Stream-Source.repo`

```
[baseos-source]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - BaseOS - Source
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/Source
#  /usr/libexec/platform-python -c 'import dnf, json; db = dnf.dnf.Base(); print(json.dumps(db.conf.substitutions, indent=2))' => { "arch": "x86_64", "basearch": "x86_64", "releasever": "8" }
#  See also: cd /etc/dnf/vars;grep . *  =>  contentdir:centos infra:stock stream:8-stream
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-$releasever&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

[appstream-source]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - AppStream - Source
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/AppStream/Source
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

[highavailability-source]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - HighAvailability - Source
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/HighAvailability/Source
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

[powertools-source]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - PowerTools - Source
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/PowerTools/Source
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

[centosplus-source]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - centosplus - Source
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/centosplus/Source
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

[extras-source]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - extras - Source
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/extras/Source
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1
```

So yeah, long question (sorry), but where in tarnation have they stashed the wretched source files - anyone know?  (and yes, I did JFGI before typing... 0 results as of writing)

Answer (score 0):

Update: SRPMs are now available in https://vault.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/Source/SPackages/

---

The SRPMs aren't currently available.

According to [Johnny Hughes](https://wiki.centos.org/JohnnyHughes) on the [CentOS mailing list](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2020-December/075736.html) (17 Dec 2020):

> I'm sure src rpms will also be available in the future, once all the
> hardware and mirrors are in place (we can not support downloading
> directl off our main koji machine that controls all the builds.
>
> But in our build system, the SRPMS are built literally on the fly, from
> the commitid out of git.  We do not use srpms directly, we build from
> the git repo.

He offers these instructions for building your own SRPM:

> If you want to create the SRPM .. you would:
>
> ======= git clone https://git.centos.org/rpms/thermald
>
> cd thermald
>
> git checkout 14acf460654c5788d9c7792f36fed45c7e00a387
>
> into_srpm.sh
>
> =======
>
> You will then have the SRPM in the SRPMs dir of your git repo .. it
> will also be exploded and ready for you to use in SPECS and SOURCES to
> make changes.
>
> If you do not have the git tools downloaded .. where into_srpm.sh
> comes from, you can get it from here:
>
> git clone https://git.centos.org/centos-git-common